# How to find index of an Array of Objects

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array of Objects. I am trying to find the index of an element when a different method is called (the other method requires two integers as parameters to perform.)

```
private Object[]obj = {new Object(),new Object(),new Object()};

...

private void DoMove(AnotherObject move){
  move = new AnotherObject(int one , int two);
}
```

I tried using `Arrays.sort` then `indexOf()`, but that gave an error

> --> my Object could not be casted.

Any other ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Why do you need to sort?

Comment: you can use `obj[index]` for access to the element of your array

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to treat the array as a list with the [`Arrays.asList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList-T...-) method, and then just call [`contains`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains-java.lang.Object-):

```
if (Arrays.asList(obj).contains(move)) {
    // do stuff
}
```